# Thinking mathematically and proving things

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I'm learning about existential and universal quantifiers and one of the examples given is: The equation $x^2 + 2x +1 = 0$ has a real root. Written using an existential quantifier it looks like this:

$\exists x \mid x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$

To prove the statement above, the lecturer chose the value $-1$ which satisfies the above and the result does indeed equal $0$.

I come from a software development background so my obvious approach to finding that $x = -1$ would be to write a simple program to brute force it (which might not work).

But as a mathematician how would you approach this (introspection would be really helpful for me)? Simply brute forcing this kind of things seems the wrong way to think since there are an infinite amount of numbers.

Comment: This is a quadratic equation, and there is a simple formula for finding all solutions to that. See [Quadratic Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)

Comment: You might also recognize that the polynomial is equivalent to $(x+1)^2,$ and linear factors correspond to zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the formula for finding solutions to quadratic equations, which are equations of the form $ax^2 + bx+c=0$:

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

In your case, we have $a=1$, $b=2$, and $c=1$, so we get:

$$x = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{2^2-4}}{2}=\frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{0}}{2}=\frac{-2 }{2}=-1$$

Comment: I see, thank you. So the lecturer didn't just choose -1 out of thin air, he recognised it as a quadratic equation and solved it accordingly. Got it, thank you so much.

Comment: @00101010 Exactly! Glad I could help.

Comment: In a different context, say without the prior knowledge of the quadratic formula, a mathematician might derive the equation as a "lemma." Then use it to compute the roots of the quadratic expression.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for polynomials with degree smaller than 5 there always are formulas to solve it. The problem is that those formulas get more and more complicated once the degree is bigger than 2. See for example the formula for a quartic (degree 4) polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function  What's also handy is using newton's method to find the (real) roots. It always works for non-trivial polynomials. (Don't try $(x-5)^7$ because you already know the roots.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to Newton's method, I hadn't even considered how to approach an n-th degree polynomial so this helps me understand the thinking behind approaching mathematical problems.

Comment: There are lots of numerical methods for finding roots. For example, if you have a function for which you don't know the derivative, then you can use the Secant method which works really well with a rate of convergence of $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, the golden ratio (nice, huh?). There are also modified Newton methods which (try to) speed up the process of root finding by guessing the convergence rate during each iteration; also works with multidimensional function, but you need a non-singular Jacobian, a derivative matrix with non-zero determinant, to execute. There are plenty more of them.